# $C^{\ast}$-algebra approach to classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Can someone please help me understand how classical mechanics (for example in terms of Hamiltonian formalism) can be described in terms of $C^{\ast}$-algebras? I read usually that in this case the algebra need to be abelian, but I never found enough material which properly explains how phase space and Poisson brakets (so time evolution and transformations as space traslation) are described and introduced in a $C^{\ast}$-algebra formalism.

Comment: The buzzword is [Koopman-von Neumann mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics).